# Web Server Upgrade from 14.04 to 20.04 ( can't load web page error: Unable to load Database Driver: mysqli)

Tags: server, upgrade, apache2, php, lamp

I badly need help, I just want to say first that I am a newbie with web server. My boss was asking to me to upgrade our web server to the latest version Ubuntu 20.04 LTS as the old was running with 14.04. I've installed the distribution and a LAMP Stack on my desktop as I would like to try it first with my own computer before touching the server. I've installed Apache2, PHP 7.4.3 and mySQL 8.0 however the versions running on the old server are PHP 5.x and MySQL 5.x. I copied all the files over from `/var/www/` and the Apache configuration files from `/etc/apache2` then created a SQL dump and migrated to the the new mysql database (I made sure that permissions are the same with the old server). However, every time I open `localhost` in a browser, I see this error message:

```
Database Error: Unable to load Database Driver: mysqli
```

Update: Database error has been sorted out by the steps provided by Matigo below.

Here is my new situation, I still can't access my website as localhost as it only shows the word "Error"

Error log says:

Failed to read session data: user (path: /var/lib/php/sessions) in /var/www/kssp/libraries/joomla/session/handler/native.php on line 194

I really appreciate the help guys!

btw this how the session dir looks like: not sure if i need to do chmod for this.

drwxr-xr-x 3 root root 4096 Feb  8 22:55 modules
drwx-wx-wt 2 root root 4096 Mar 27  2020 sessions

Issue Resolved:

Steps taken:

- Uninstall - Reinstall LAMP Server
- Verified if all php-modules were enabled
- Created mysql database backup from old server
- Recreated mysql database in the new server
- Recreated database user pass to the new server and made sure it matches   - Allowed Override All on Apache2.conf
- Enabled rewrite module

Everything on the website now looks exactly the same with my localhost/server.

Next is to map the ip address and point the A record.

I'm happy that this has been sorted out, thanks to Matigo for enlightening me with the steps.

Comment: Silly question, but have you installed the database driver? If not, then `sudo apt install php-mysql` followed by `sudo service apache2 restart` will resolve that issue 

Comment: @Matigo- Thanks for responding, Yes I have already installed the database driver and it's running on the latest version. "php-mysql version (2:7.4+75)"

Comment: Is there anything more specific in your `/var/log/apache2` directory? You might see something in the `error.log` that is letting you know what's wrong. This can also be caused by something in the PHP code if there is a hard reference somewhere ...

Comment: Here's what I'm getting via error log. And there are multiple same lines as this: 

:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'pdo_mysql.so' (tried: /usr/lib/php/20190902/pdo_mysql.so (/usr/lib/php/20190902/pdo_mysql.so: undefined symbol: mysqlnd_allocator), /usr/lib/php/201909

Comment: Can you confirm that you have a `/etc/php/7.4/mods-available/pdo_mysql.ini` file, and that in that file you have `extension=pdo_mysql.so` with no preceding `;`? From what I can tell, you should be running a stock Apache/PHP config.

Comment: Hi @Matigo, sorry, it took me hours to reply, just needed to take a deep rest as this project is really something. Yes I do have extension=pdo_mysql.so  on php.sql.ini file without ;

Comment: Thank you for your advise @Matigo,   Error is still the same at this point.

Comment: I re-installed LAMP and the PHP error was gone, however it's still the same when I'm trying to launch the website as localhost. I'm still getting an error:

Comment: Perhaps you could update your question to include the new situation, then?

Comment: Thank you Matigo, I updated the question with the details.  Just need more advise on what to check, sorry for being a pain, just need to wrap my brain around this web server admin process.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the persistent error, the issue (in my mind) comes down to one of a few cases:

1. `php-mysql` is not installed, or is not the correct version for PHP 7.4
2. The `php-mysqlnd` helper package is not installed (this generally comes with `php-mysql`, so should not require attention)
3. Apache has not been restarted since updating PHP
4. The `mysqli` extension is commented out in its `ini` file

So, let's do some testing by creating a dummy PHP file in your web root that calls the `phpinfo()` function:

0. Open Terminal (if it's not already open)
1. Create a dummy PHP file in the web root:

   ```
   sudo vi /var/www/testing.php
   ```

   ***Notes:***
   • *Feel free to use any other editor that you prefer. The use of* `vi` *is more about muscle memory than an implicit endorsement for the editor.*
   • *Be sure to change* `/var/www` *to the actual document root location for* `http://localhost`
2. Paste this into the new file:

   ```
   <?php phpinfo(); ?>
   ```
3. Save the file
4. Open your browser and access `http://localhost/testing.php`. This should give you a PHP information page that looks something like this:
   [image: PHP Information]
5. Scroll down (or use the Find function) to locate the section titled `mysqli`. It should look something like this:
   [image: PHP Info - MySQLi]

Now comes the "fun" part.

**If you see a blank page when visiting `testing.php` ...**
⇢ PHP is not configured correctly. For simplicity's sake, remove and re-install:

```
sudo apt install --reinstall php libapache2-mod-php php-mysql
```

Then restart Apache:

```
sudo service apache2 restart
```

**If you see the PHP Info page, but nothing for mysqli ...**
⇢ `mysqli` is either not installed or not configured correctly.

- Confirm that `mysqli` for PHP 7.4 is installed by opening a terminal (or using the current one) and typing `sudo apt install php7.4-mysql` (Note that we are specifically calling the package for 7.4 here. This should not be necessary, but we want to be 100% certain it's the correct version for your PHP installation)

  If everything is installed properly, you will see a message like this:

  ```
  Reading package lists... Done
  Building dependency tree       
  Reading state information... Done
  php7.4-mysql is already the newest version (7.4.3-4ubuntu2.4).
  0 to upgrade, 0 to newly install, 0 to remove and 2 not to upgrade.
  ```
- Confirm that the `mysqli.ini` file exists and is configured correctly by opening a terminal (or using the one that's currently open), navigating to the `conf.d` directory for PHP and Apache, and listing MySQL-related files:

  ```
  cd /etc/php/7.4/apache2/conf.d
  ll *mysql*
  ```

  You should see something like this:

  ```
  lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 39  5月  9  2020 10-mysqlnd.ini -> /etc/php/7.4/mods-available/mysqlnd.ini
  lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 38  5月  9  2020 20-mysqli.ini -> /etc/php/7.4/mods-available/mysqli.ini
  lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 41  5月  9  2020 20-pdo_mysql.ini -> /etc/php/7.4/mods-available/pdo_mysql.ini
  ```

  If you do not see these files, then `php-mysql` was not correctly installed. Let's try again:

  ```
  sudo apt install --reinstall php-mysql
  ```

  Open the `20-mysqli.ini` file and ensure the contents of the file matches this:

  ```
  ; configuration for php mysql module
  ; priority=20
  extension=mysqli.so
  ```

  Restart Apache:

  ```
  sudo service apache2 restart
  ```

  If everything matches, open the `mysqlnd.ini` file. This file *must* be loaded before `mysqli`, so it will probably be prefixed with `10-` in the directory. Ensure the `extension=mysqlnd.so` line does not have a `;` in front of it.

**If everything so far has matched your configuration ...**
⇢ The problem is most likely in the application code itself and may need to be examined by a developer familiar with the system to make the changes necessary to work with the newer technology stack.

Rarely do I see Apache installations require this much effort unless you're migrating something with really obscure requirements. Most LAMP stacks are painfully simple, as a lot of people have made the tools a lot easier to use over the last decade or so.

Hopefully something here will help you resolve the issue.

Comment: Matigo, I followed each and every detailed step you provided and it was really helpful, I found out that mysqli was missing.

I also recreated the database and uploaded the sql dump. I got rid of the mysqli error how ever I still cannot load the website as localhost.

my apache error log now shows: 

 PHP Warning:  session_start(): Failed to read session data: user (path: /var/lib/php/sessions) in /var/www/kssp/libraries/joomla/session/handler/native.php on line 260

Comment: For Joomla, you might want to confirm [the technical requirements with PHP and Apache](https://downloads.joomla.org/technical-requirements) to ensure you have the correct modules and extensions enabled. However, looking over the warning, I’d say you need some additional PHP packages: `sudo apt install php7.4-zip php7.4-dev php7.4-xml php7.4-json php7.4-mbstring`. Be sure to restart Apache after installing these.